# mySQL getting multiple arguments for single column from URL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that outputs data to this:

```
index.php?city=ADDIEVILLE&city=ALBERS&city=ALHAMBRA
```

Then need to go into a mysql where statement like so:

```
WHERE CITY = ADDIEVILLE OR CITY = ALBERS OR CITY = ALHAMBRA
```

How would I be able to pass those multiple cities along to the mySQL query using PHP?

Comment: In your form, you should _not_ have multiple elements with `name='city'` instead, you should define them all with the same name as an array `name='city[]'`  Then `$_GET['city']` will itself be an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index.php?city=ADDIEVILLE&city=ALBERS&city=ALHAMBRA`

would print as: `$_GET['city']='ALHAMBRA';`

whereas:

`index.php?city[]=ADDIEVILLE&city[]=ALBERS&city[]=ALHAMBRA`

would print as an array.

this could then be transformed into:

```
$cities = $_GET['city'];

$str = "CITY='".implode("' OR CITY='",$cities)."'";
echo $str;
```

Note: `$cities` should be sanatized for injections.

Comment: It's not passing it through as `city[]` but as `city%5B%5D`

Comment: it would appear it is encoding the URL

Answer (score 1):

As [@MichaelBerkowski says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146225/mysql-getting-multiple-arguments-for-single-column-from-url-query/14146300#comment19591285_14146225), you should use `city[]` as your field name, then you can do something like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);

$qry = $dbh->prepare('
  SELECT *
  FROM   my_table
  WHERE  CITY IN ('.implode(',', array_fill(0, count($_GET['city']), '?')).')
');

$qry->execute($_GET['city']);
```

Comment: First select multiple.  Thanks.